# Assign A Numerical Value to Non-Numerical Text in Excel for Rota

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to come up with a way to calculate the hours in Excel automatically for my rota. The issue I'm running into is that we do not list "off times" on the schedule, so the shifts are input as "12-cls" or "5-LB".

I am trying to find a way to assign the number 10 to "5-LB" or 8 to "holiday" for example, but I am having a hard time finding the right formula for it. Currently, I just have the shift and its prospective hours that I manually click and add using =Sum(). It would be awesome if I could find a formula that would let me just highlight someone's schedule and automatically add up the hours. Below is an example image of our rota.

[image: example of rota]

Comment: Hi, sorry your post isn't very clear about what these short codes mean or why they have the durations listed in your screenshot. Also you have not elaborated on what formulae you have tried already, which will likely lead to your question being closed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like VLOOKUP to replace each text cell with its value equivalent, using your summary table as reference, eg.

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$J$3:$I$11,2,FALSE)
```

If are familiar with array formulae, you can do a whole row all at once and just add up:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(B4:H4,$J$3:$I$11,2,FALSE))
```

Remember to enter this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in old versions of Excel.